# how to place a check that user can login only once in a day Android?

Tags: android

i have been thinking for hours but i find no way, no solution, can any body help me or give me a logical idea? or some lines of code? i am getting cuurent time and adding 24 hours extra when user trying second time to login but its not working for me.
here is my code for getting current time.

```
    public void getTime() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    time = strDate.replace(":", "");

    previous_time = Integer.parseInt(time);
    saveToSharesPre(previous_time + 2400);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create shared preference for login_date. Whenever user logs in, check whether the current date is greater than the login_date from shared preference. If it is greater allow the user to login and update the login_date. Now if the user logs in for the second time in a day, the current date will not be greater than login_date, hence restrict him from logging in by showing some alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for hour also.Put hour instead of date in shared preference as say Monish Kamble.